# Circular model dependencies with ruby on rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, models

I'm trying to design the database model hierarchy and the migrations for my database for a group chat app and I'm new to rails so I'm quite confused about how I should build this... Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

It breaks down as follows:

Groups <==> Users <==> Posts
Groups ==> Posts

So the groups have a bunch of users and users have a bunch of groups, but also the groups have the posts that the users make.  Each post belongs to one group and one user. The post must also maintain a reference to the user that posted it.

Should I just make a joined table of all 3? Is that practical/efficient?

I'm just confused where I should use `belongs_to`, `has_one`, `has_many`, `has_and_belongs_to_many` and how I should write the migration files...

thanks for any help ahead of time

Comment: Forget about rails. First decide the feature you want and find out entities enrolled in that. After that find out relation between every entity. List of attributes of that entity can be decided after that.

Answer (score 2):

you can do it in next way

Groups

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :users
has_many :posts
```

Users

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :groups
has_many :posts
```

Posts

```
belongs_to :group
belongs_to :user
```

`posts` table should have `group_id` and `user_id` columns
also create table `groups_users`
migration:

```
class CreateGroupsUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :groups_users, id: false do |t|
      t.references :group, index: true
      t.references :user, index: true
    end
  end
end
```

This should work!

**EDIT**

for adding association between User and Group:

```
group = Group.create(name: 'New Group')
user = User.last
user.groups << group
```

or

```
user.build_group(name: 'New Group')
user.save
```

or you can use nested_attributes

```
User.create(params[:user])
```

where `params[:user] = {user_name: 'James Bond', group_attributes: {name: 'New Group'}}`

Comment: Thanks, where does the groups_users table come in??

Comment: you should create this table without model. HABTM works in this way. [LOOK HEAR](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association)

Comment: Do I need to put anything in the user / group migration files to support it?

Comment: no, it works through `groups_users` table. Just add associations to model.

Comment: Looking good so far, now when creating the users/groups how do I establish the link between the two (add an entry in the groups_users table)?